# Converting every 60-seconds data into 1-minute data using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a second-wise data like this (more than 86000 rows of data, from 2022-07-01 to 2022-07-02.)

```
Datetime                Data1   Data2                   ...     Data85          Data86
2022-07-01 23:57:39 9.831   4.984511        ... -0.01333    0.74176 
2022-07-01 23:57:40 9.426   4.984511            ... -0.01333    0.73347
.
.
.   
2022-07-02 23:57:41 9.605   4.984511        ... -0.01333    0.74576 
2022-07-02 23:57:42 9.605   4.984511        ... -0.01333    0.74576
```

I want to convert this to minute-wise data (not every minute has 60 data). So, what I need is summing the minute's second-wise data and dividing by the amount of data (averaging). To get like this,

```
Datetime                Data1   Data2                   ...     Data85          Data86
2022-07-01 23:57    9.831   4.984511        ... -0.01333    0.74176 
2022-07-01 23:58    9.821   4.984611        ... -0.01333    0.74176 

2022-07-02 23:59    ...
```

Comment: I submitted an edit to fix the visibility should be approved shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by `resample()`:

> resample() is a time-based groupby, followed by a reduction method on
> each of its groups. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling

`df.resample('60S').mean()`

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful. I read the documentation; it should be what I am needing now. Still facing some problems like "Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'", but let me see if I can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the average across multiple data frames or a single column?
If you are only try to get the average of the data in a single column you can run a `.mean()` on it.

Example:

```py
output = dataframe["column"].mean()
```

Comment: I am sorry, it's not what I want. .mean() will get me one average answer for each column. What I require now is every minute.